# How to treat one directory in a URL as a param?

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting, get

I am sure that I need to use some rewrite condition for this, but I can't quite get my head around it.

As an example URL:

`https://example.com/guest-area/{TENANT-NAME}/login`

Here, `{TENANT-NAME}` should be treated as a GET param by PHP, so really the URL is treated as:

`https://example.com/guest-area/login/?tenant={TENANT-NAME}`

However, it should appear in the address bar as the first example and be accessible to the user like this.

The value of `{TENANT_ID}` will always come after `/guest-area`, so whatever is given in between the next set of forward slashes should be treated as `$_GET['tenant']` and not a directory. Any directories after it (e.g. `/login`) are 'real' ones.

Comment: If URL is `https://myurl.com/guest-area/{TENANT-ID}/foo/bar/baz` then what would be internal handler URL for this?

Answer (score 1):

put this in your .htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^guest-area/(.*)/login /guest-area/login/?tenant=$1
RewriteRule ^guest-area/(.*)/login/ /guest-area/login/?tenant=$1
```

Comment: There will be multiple possible directories (and multiple levels) that will appear after 'guest-area/{TENANT-ID}'. So for example: ```https://myurl.com/guest-area/{TENANT-ID}/foo/bar/``` ... and so on. Is there a way to account for this using regex?

Comment: @Elliot RewriteRule ^guest-area/(.*)/(.*)$ /guest-area/$2?tenant=$1