# How to express a URL rewrite condition to replace the name of the 1st directory if it does not exist?

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, get

Given the example URL:

`https://example.com/{SOME-ID}/foo/bar`

How would a URL rewrite be achieved such that:

1. The value of `{SOME-ID}` is not a real directory on the server, and it would otherwise throw a 404 error
2. The server replaces `{SOME-ID}` with the directory `guest-area` (which *does* exist on the server)
3. The value of `{SOME-ID}` is treated as a GET parameter

Now, the URL is treated by the server as:

`https://example.com/guest-area/foo/bar/?q={SOME-ID}`

The rewrite condition needs to account for **any number of subdirectories** after `guest-area` (or no subdirectories after it).

Only the **first** directory (i.e., `{SOME-ID}`) should be replaced with `guest-area`. All others after it should stay as part of the URL and be assumed to be real directories.

The rewrite should also only happen in the event that `{SOME-ID}` is **not** a real directory.

For context, all files in `guest-area` (and any of its subdirectories) will include a handler for the value of `$_GET['q']`, which will either load the page or throw a 404 if `{SOME-ID}` is not a recognised value. I don't believe this has any bearing on how the rewrite conditions would be expressed, though.

Comment: This is not much different from what you asked here already, https://stackoverflow.com/q/73449856/1427878 You will just have to match the last part dynamically and insert it into the substitution URL again.

Comment: And you asked about this already in comments under this answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/73449988/1427878 - and got a response to that as well. Anything not working with that ...?

Answer (score 0):

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(.*)$ /$2?q=$1 [L,QSA]

Usage =

These rules will allow you to rewrite a URL with {SOME-ID} in it to guest-area/?q={SOME-ID}. The value of {SOME-ID} will be treated as a GET parameter.